# Android Studio, JSON

Tags: android, json, listview

Приветствую! Как организовать "правильный" JSON запрос. Скажем мне необходимо получить определенные данные с сервера. (другими словами юзеры должны видеть только свои записи)

Если делать так:

// url получения списка всех продуктов

```
private static String url_all_order = "http://example.com/api/get_order.php";
```

в то же время на сервере в get_order.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());
```

То все работает, выводится в ListView все данные с таблицы.

А вот если в запросе .php добавить:

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM order WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
```

А в .java добавить

```
private static String url_all_order = "http://example.com/api/get_order.php?id=2";
```

То приложение вылетает.

Вот полный код рабочий (который все данные в листвью отображает):

```
public class AllOrderActivity extends ListActivity  {


private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Создаем JSON парсер
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url получения списка всех продуктов
private static String url_all_order = "http://example.com/api/get_order.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "order";
private static final String TAG_PID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "note";

// тут будет хранится список продуктов
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_order);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Загружаем прожукты в фоновом потоке
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // получаем ListView
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // на выбор одного продукта
    // запускается Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Запускаем новый intent который покажет нам Activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditOrderActivity.class);
            // отправляем pid в следующий activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // запуская новый Activity ожидаем ответ обратно
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}


// Ответ из Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // если результующий код равен 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // если полученный код результата равен 100
        // значит пользователь редактирует или удалил продукт
        // тогда мы перезагружаем этот экран
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Фоновый Async Task для загрузки всех продуктов по HTTP запросу
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом фонового потока Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllOrderActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка. Подождите...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Получаем все продукт из url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Будет хранить параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // получаем JSON строк с URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_order, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Получаем SUCCESS тег для проверки статуса ответа сервера
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // продукт найден
                // Получаем масив из Продуктов
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // перебор всех продуктов
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Сохраняем каждый json елемент в переменную
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // Создаем новый HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // продукт не найден
                // Запускаем Add New Product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewOrderActivity.class);
                // Закрытие всех предыдущие activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем прогрес диалог
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // закрываем прогресс диалог после получение все продуктов
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // обновляем UI форму в фоновом потоке
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Обновляем распарсенные JSON данные в ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllOrderActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                        TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // обновляем listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

  }
 }
```

А вот php:

```
  <?php

$response = array();
require 'db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$response["order"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $product = array();
    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["date"] = $row["date"];
    $product["note"] = $row["note"];
    $product["status"] = $row["status"];

    array_push($response["order"], $product);
}
$response["success"] = 1;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No order found";

echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Ошибка приложения:

> 07-13 20:17:20.736 14853-14903/com,exemple.api E/Buffer Error﹕ Error
>   converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
>
> 07-13 20:17:20.736 14853-14903/com,exemple.api E/JSON Parser﹕ Error
>   parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
>
> 07-13 20:17:20.736 14853-14903/com,exemple.api E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Process: com,exemple.api , PID: 14853

Comment: Добавьте ошибку с которой вылетает приложение.

Comment: Unfortunately, App has stopped

Comment: @AVR как выглядит JSON который пришел с сервера при запросе по id, т.е. что выводится в LogCat командой ```Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());``` ?

Comment: LogCat выдает, когда не используется `WHERE` в php и в `url_all_order` не добавлен `?id=2` : `D/All Products:﹕ {"im_order":[{"id":"2","date":"2015-07-10 00:00:00","note":"sadasd","status":"0"},{"id":"5","date":"2015-07-10 22:58:50","note":"534","status":"0"},{"id":"2","date":"2015-07-10 23:02:57","note":"eert","status":"0"},{"id":"5","date":"2015-07-13 19:14:04","note":"kairhan","status":"0"}],"success":1}` и Выдает ошибку на дисплее Девайса `Unfortunately, App has stopped` когда делаем выбор данных по id при этом в логкат ни чего не приходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено.
Нужно было добавить:

```
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "2"));
```

Перед строкой:

```
 // получаем JSON строк с URL
     JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_order, "GET", params);
```